# Javascript delay a mousedown event

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
document.onmousedown = function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){ e }, 3000);
};
```

This is just pseudo code, but I want to capture the mousedown event and fire it later. It doesn't matter if it fires the first time or not (ie preventdefault).

If this was a click event I know I could just save the clientX, clientY of e and reinitialize the event, but I couldn't find any way to simulate mouse down with JavaScript.

Comment: What's the reason why you want to delay the mousedown event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
document.onmousedown = (args) =>
  setTimeout(() => fn.apply(null, [args]), 500)

var fn = (args) => {
  console.log('onmousedown args', args)
}
```

```html
Click anywhere and check the console (wait for it)
```

If I understand you correctly this will allow you to execute that `onmousedown` event at a later time with the same params.

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/xk0ew4yh/16/)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trigger a **mousedown** event, just use this api [MouseEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent)

> The MouseEvent() constructor creates a new MouseEvent.

The code is like this:

```
var trigger = false
document.onmousedown = function(e){
    var t = new MouseEvent('mousedown',e)
    console.log(t)
    if(!trigger)
    {
        trigger = true;
        document.dispatchEvent(t)
    }
};
```

Comment: If OP confirms this works I'll upvote. Can't be bothered to test it myself :p

Comment: This does indeed work thank you! I just found Akrion's answer more complete.

Comment: Thanks @YAHsaves! I just thought this was a clever solution that likely preserves more detail, and does so in a way that I've never seen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

**HTML Code:**

```
<p id="myParaid">
Click the text! The mouseDown() function is triggered when the mouse button is pressed down over this paragraph, 
</p>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$( "#myParaid" ).mousedown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .mousedown() called." );
  setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
});
function myFunction(){
alert('3000 Over');
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/7636/)

Comment: Why did you feel the need to introduce jQuery? Not to mention this does nothing different than what OP already has.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem. Maybe somewhere else replace the onmousedown listenter.
It's best you use addEventListener

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
setTimeout(function() {
   //your code here
}, 3000)});
```

or if you are using jQuery, you can use this code

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //your code here
    }, 3000);
});
```